# Pick values inside the JSON object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

In my application, I am reading the dict of keys user is interested in then returning just those in the reply object. User can specify different key name.

My solution works when I just pass JSON object.

```
     import * as _ from 'lodash';

     originalData = {
        "Cat" : "Cat Value",
        "Dog" : "Dog Value",
        "Rat" : "Rat Value"
     }

      transformMap = {
         "Cat" : "catData",
         "Dog" : "DogData"
      }

      let reply: any = {}
      let Keys = _.keys(transformMap)

      // Extract only the keys user wants.
      let filter = _.pick(originalData , Keys );
      if(!_.isEmpty(filter )) {
         Object.keys(filter).forEach(function (key) {
           reply[transformMap[key]] = originalData[key];
         });
      }
```

For this the output is -

```
   reply= {
        "catData" : "Cat Value",
        "DogData" : "Dog Value"
     }
```

The above code works but I want to apply similar functionality when the original data is of type array -

```
    originalData = [
        {
          "Cat" : "Cat Value1",
          "Dog" : "Dog Value1",
          "Rat" : "Rat Value1"
        },
        {
           "Cat" : "Cat Value2",
           "Dog" : "Dog Value2",
           "Rat" : "Rat Value2"
        }
     ]

    reply= [
        {
          "catData" : "Cat Value1",
          "DogData" : "Dog Value1"
        },
        {
          "catData" : "Cat Value2",
          "DogData" : "Dog Value2"
        }
    ]
```

Is there a way I can achieve result for both types of output?

Answer (score 0):

Package up your "key transformer" into a function. Then wrap it in something with flexible inputs.

```
function transformAnything(data, tranformMap) {
  const usingArray = data instanceof Array;

  const arrayData = usingArray ? data : [data];

  const transformedData = arrayData.map(
    objectData => tranformObjectData(objectData, tranformMap)
  );

  return usingArray ? transformedData : transformedData[0];
}
```

Comment: ok.. But my question is - Is there there way I pick fields without manually looping through the array? lodash _.pick does not work when I want it to pick object data from array.

Comment: You want a version of `pick` that handles this array structure? I don't think that comes with lodash. I'm suggesting you write your own, thus my answer.